# export Arabic text with foxpro

Tags: database, xls, visual-foxpro

I am trying to export  arabic text from my database table in visual foxpro (9) to an Excel sheet, but the Arabic script appears as Latin characters, the inverse (Excel to foxpro) workes good

Comment: Does adding the AS codepage clause to your COPY TO or EXPORT command help?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your PC windows control panel to region and language and open it.
in the administrative tab click the button Change System Locale, you will be prompted to choose the Locale language choose an Arabic language of your choice, and hit OK, on the same administrative tab
another button is there called Copy settings, click on it, when prompted (Copy your current settings to ?) check booth options then click OK.
Now go to Fox-Pro and Tools, options, regional, and check the (use system settings) if already checked check again, hit Save as Defaults, OK.
last things to do, Exit Fox-pro, and restart your PC.
Try exporting Arabic text again if it works (great) if not the Arabic text in the fox-pro table was inserted using none Arabic supported keyboard or operating system.